# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS constantly crashing in multiple Mini Pc Asus Amd Ryzen 7 4700u

Tags: 22.04, asus, crash

I have been using serveral Mini Pc Asus Amd Ryzen 7 4700u with different configurations that range from 32gb memory to 64gb and 500gb SSD disk to 1Tb but from February I started experimenting OS crashes.

Crash details: it completely freezes, then a black screen for 1/2 seconds and then freeze again. It doesn't respond to keyboard and mouse.

Additional data:

- If I use WhatsApp desktop (any version) it crashes very fast
- Having more tabs open make it crash faster
- A computer with hardware encryption crashes much faster
- Syslog: https://pastebin.com/5k0HG0mL

Any insights?

Thanks!

Comment: Are your machines up to the latest firmware patches from the vendor?

Comment: yes, I have the last update

Comment: Change 18.04 tag to 22.04.  Ever do a memory check?  What does SMART (smartmontools package) report for you disk?  Please include the /proc/cmdline in your original posting so we can see how the kernel was run. What UEFI Settings on things like iommu, ...etc.

Comment: I have 3 computers with the same setup with the same problem, and the problem appeared after January. It is not a disk or memory issue.